# ios6 file upload not working with digest authentication?

Tags: file-upload, web, ios6

I [heard iPhone ios6 is able to upload files](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers).

I have a [very simple PHP upload form](https://github.com/kaihendry/FTP2.0/blob/master/upload.php) and it doesn't work.

[image: ios6 file upload not working]

I've used this PHP script for years on my desktop (Chrome or Firefox or curl), where it works fine. Interesting Chromium on ios6 which IIUC uses Safari errors out with "[Missing file](https://github.com/kaihendry/FTP2.0/blob/master/upload.php#L6)".

Any ideas where I might be going wrong? I'm a Archlinux user so I'm not privy to MacOSX etc.

**Update**: I have a reduced test case here http://ios6.dabase.com/ where the problem seems to be uploading with digest authentication enabled (that's how I roll).

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/hendry/8013346479

Comment: I've logged Problem ID: 12368352

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your input tag to support the new [HTML 5 media capture API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/).

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```